# For python-dotenv, is it better practice to use dotenv.load_dotenv() or dotenv.dotenv_values(".env")?

Tags: python, python-dotenv

Is it better practice to use `dotenv.load_dotenv()` or `dotenv.dotenv_values(".env")`?

In most examples that I've seen, people use `load_dotenv()`, with the os module. Is this better than simply using the `dotenv_values()`, which just returns a dict? Or are there times when one is more appropriate to use than the other?

I'm currently using env = dotenv_values(".env"), but wanted to see if there were reasons others tend to use `load_dotenv()`

Comment: If you want the env file to be loaded into the actual environment (which is always my use case), use `load_dotenv()`.  Otherwise if you want to read an env file and return the values into a plain variable, use `dotenv_values()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Along with what John Gordon says, if you *don't* want the .env file to override values in the environment, *don't* use `load_dotenv`.

Comment: According to the documentation: By default, load_dotenv doesn't override existing environment variables.